# how to add a nest array as one data attribute Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This might not be possible but I have a nest array and what to add two values to a data attribute. At the moment when I add this it does it like data-genre= "comedy,romance". I want to get them as two different values such as data-cat="comedy" data-genre"romance" but for the one DOM.

Comment: Please take the time to rethink your question, your example cannot work as it is (the order of some lines is not right, data.comedy doesn't even exist) and personally i have an hard figuring out what your actual problem is, what have you tried ? can't you iterate over your JSON array and then on each "genre" array ? Can't you use destructuring ? Are the number of items constant ? If yes, can't you just use indexes ? What's the actual problem here ?

Comment: You can serialize the genre array as JSON and set that JSON string as the attribute value (example: https://jsfiddle.net/bzqrsof6/). If that addresses your question, I can write up as an answer. If not, what did I miss?

Comment: I have add more to my question

Comment: how do I then use them as different values?

Answer (score 1):

`data.genre` does not exist, so I presume you meant `data[0].genre`. Just join the array for `box.dataset`:

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "movie_name": "last holiday",
    "date": "2023-10-29",
    "genre": ["comedy", "romance"],
  },

  {
    "id": 2,
    "movie_name": "pitch perfect",
    "date": "2023-04-24",
    "genre": [
      "comedy"
    ]
  }
]

box.dataset.genre = data[0].genre.join(` `);
```

```css
#box::before {
  content: 'Your genre data-attribute is set to: ';
}

#box::after {
  content: attr(data-genre);
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

After the edit of your question: you can't use the same id (`#box`) twice, id should be unique. Here's a snippet that adds the two entries as elements to `div#box` and sets the data-attribute for it.

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "movie_name": "last holiday",
    "date": "2023-10-29",
    "genre": ["comedy", "romance"],
  },

  {
    "id": 2,
    "movie_name": "pitch perfect",
    "date": "2023-04-24",
    "genre": [
      "comedy"
    ]
  }
];

data.forEach(movie => {
  const movieElem = document.querySelector(`#box`)
   .insertAdjacentElement( `beforeend`,
     Object.assign(
       document.createElement(`div`), 
      { innerHTML: `${movie.movie_name} (${movie.date}), genre(s): ` } ) );
  movieElem.dataset.genre = movie.genre.join(` `);
});
```

```css
[data-genre]::after {
  content: attr(data-genre);
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```